# Jquery $.post doesnt work on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I'm having a problem but I couldn't solve it.

**my code is working on firefox perfectly**.

I have two list boxes: the first one contains countries, the second contains cities. If you change country, the cities list in the second list box.

my jquery code:

```
$('#country').change(function(){

var sec=$('#country').val();

    $.post(
            'select.php?do=country',
            {s:sec},
            function(answer){
                $('#city').html(answer);
            }
    );

});
```

when I changed country nothing happens in google chrome.

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is all of this code wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` method?

Chrome parses faster than ffox and therefore the binding of the `change` function could be  taking place before the DOM is ready. Without using a DOM ready function, the element with id `country` might not be rendered by the browser.

```
$(function() {
// or $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#country').change(function(){

  var sec=$('#country').val();

    $.post(
            'select.php?do=country',
            {s:sec},
            function(answer){
                $('#city').html(answer);
            }
    );

  });
```

});

Comment: I tried this in jsfiddle.  If you use `no wrap (head)`, it doesn't work in either FF or chrome.  If you use `no wrap (body)`, it works in both...  http://jsfiddle.net/KpdXL/1/.  It's hard to say without having OP's actual code to benchmark with and knowing what versions of Chrome/FF are being used.

Comment: yes its wrapped by $(document).ready() but there is to many function before .change. ı cleaned them now it works. ty.

Comment: @bayburt: Where you getting errors before?  You can check for errors using the Console in Chrome (`CTRL+SHIFT+J`).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to wrapping the code in an "onload function" you can place the js at the bottom of the file, this is recomenden for page performace reasons and it parses the script properly as well.